# Figuring out how Webpack assigns loaders

Tags: webpack

I have a project build with webpack. It's working *sometimes* on *some OSes*. On Windows it doesn't, on Macs it always works, on Linuxes it works sometimes, depending (failing on Gitlab's CI docker machine).

We've traced the problem to the exclude regular expression - it doesn't always work. We basically want to exclude `node_modules` *except for three directories inside it*. After playing with the pattern for days, we still can't get it to work in all environments (although it's relatively straight forward). Switching to include patterns instead of exclude patterns didn't really work.

Since I couldn't find any way to tell Webpack to report exactly how it tests the pattern (a log like "matching  to : MATCH/NO MATCH" is what I need), I decided to look at the Webpack sources. Sure enough, there's a `ModuleFilenameHelper.js` file that has a `matchPart` method that seems to be the one responsible for this. However, **it is never called** .

Instead there's a very complicated chain of resolvers and plugins that get called, that *somehow* decides which loaders to apply to a module. It starts with `NormarlModuleFactory.resolveRequestArray`. I spent two hours tracing this code, and I still can't figure out what it does, or where it ends, or why nobody bothered to document it so it's even remotely possible to understand what's going on there.

How can I figure out *exactly* how webpack applies the regular expressions?

Comment: It looks like the condition in your exclude could also be a function according to the spec: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#condition. It might be helpful to try and use a function to console.log what the inputs look like to help with your regex

Comment: I figured that out just now, after finally finding the right place in the code. You should really turn this into an answer.